# 404 can not update natty multiverse

Tags: 11.04, updates, software-sources

It first happend about a week ago that I received this error message the first time. It shows up daily.

> W:Failed to fetch
>   http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/multiverse/source/Sources
>   404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.30 80] , E:Some index files failed to
>   download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I can do updates from other ppa as usual. I noticed that problem in relation to special ppa defined by the user, but I can't imagine that natty's multiverse could be down for days.
Is there something I can check on my system to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try changing the server that you attempt to connect to for Multiverse (and other) updates.

Open Synaptic Package Manager and click on Settings > Repositories, then in the dropdown selection that is labeled "Download From:" choose Other.  Click the "Select Best Server" button, and after it has run some speed tests and chosen one for you, click "OK" or "Choose Server."

Update your package lists -- either click Reload in Synaptic, or in terminal type

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Hopefully this will allow you to grab new Multiverse updates!

Comment: Many thanks. I didn't notice the option "Select Best Server" before. apt-get update ran without issues.

Comment: Huzzah!  Glad to help.